# Power Supply and Motherboard

Tags: power-supply

I recently bought a new psu, as the old one (corsair cx750m) was overheating.  The new model (a cooler master masterwatt 750) does not seem to work, as in a light on the motherboard turns on, but the motherboard itself wont even begin to turn on.  (The gigabyte motherboards have a small display that tells what its doing in startup so you can check for errors, but the display doesnt even start).  The first fear is that the motherboard was screwed, but it works just fine with a friends old psu.  all the psu's work fine with a power tester, so what could the reason be?

Comment: Does the new PSU have enough wattage to cover your usage? It has a lower wattage than your old one.

Comment: Have you plugged in everything else? (HDDs etc) some PSUs need a load to start.

Comment: excuse me that was a typo, they are both 750.  I believe everything else was plugged in, I guess I could retry that route.

Comment: I second @DigitalLightcraft's question-- Embarrassingly (I worked in the field for about 5 years before this happened), I forgot to plug in the auxiliary to the motherboard... took me only a few seconds to realize what happened, but still.

Comment: Hehe, we've all been there... its a properly bad day when you forget the CPU Heatsink.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft I hadn't plugged in everything in yet, just checking to see if it would boot to the bios but hadn't plugged the hard drivers (or maybe the graphics card either).  I can try rechecking it with everything plugged in.

Comment: @wfw00d - any luck?

Comment: oh yes.  the issue was not $\textit{as}$ embarrassingly silly, but still pretty silly.  when plugging everything in and checking whether it was working or not, I didnt restart the psu in between plugging in the motherboard and everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a DOA power supply. 
To test this you can "hotwire" it:

Connect the green wire (marked PS_ON) to any of the black ground (COM) wires with a bent paperclip. 
The PSU should start - If it doesnt, it's duff, send it back.

I would suggest doing this with a HDD attached (Some PSUs wont start with no load)

[image]

Comment: I don't suggest hotwiring anything, especially with a un-insulated paperclip D: .  Another way to test if the PSU is supplying power is to plug in a DVD player or other loud spinning drive to the appropriate connector, and see if pressing the eject button opens the door.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage - I've done this safely probably hundreds of times over the past 15-20 years. You are missing the point that a PSU WONT power anything without triggering to switch on, which is done by grounding pin 16 to ground.

Comment: I've done this too with a short piece of insulated 12 gauge copper wire which is stripped at both ends (just the right size to fit into the sockets of the connector) which is why I'm reversing someone's stupid downvote.